# OIM 11gR2 PS3 Save Justification of Request on Create User

Tags: java, oim

In OIM 11gR2 PS3, When creating a user I want to save the String entered in the  Justification box of the request. When creating the user I have no workflow set, because I don't need any approvals. Do you know any way to do this??

Thank you

Comment: are you creating users manually or its a bulk load? In case of bulk load which connector are you using?

Comment: manually. I found that there is an API that has getJustification method, and I am currently trying to figure out a way to get the requests of a user with the Service Request API

Comment: you mean when you are typing the justification it is not getting saved at DB level ?

Comment: I found a solution thanks !! It is stored in the DB , but I wanted a way to get it through the API. I decided that the best way was through querying the DB, with the user login and then getting it from there ! thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: May I know the use case for which you wanted this?

Answer (score 2):

I found out that the best way to retrieve the justification of the request on create user is not through the API, but querying the DB and getting the justification field from there, given the login of the user. I also ordered the results by date, in order to retrieve the most recent request.